# Database: Pipelined Functions

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

I am new to the concept of Pipeline Functions. I have some questions regarding

From Database point of view:

- What actually is Pipeline function ?
- What is the advantage of using Pipeline Function ?
- What challenges are solved using Pipeline Function ?
- Are the any optimization advantages of using Pipeline Function ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Creating Pipelined Table Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#autoId29) in Oracle 11.2 documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote fom "Ask Tom Oracle":

> pipelined functions are simply "code you can pretend is a database table"
>
> pipelined functions give you the (amazing to me) ability to
>
> `select * from PLSQL_FUNCTION;`
>
> anytime you think you can use it -- to select * from a function, instead of a table, it
> might be "useful".

As far as advantages: a big advantage of using a Pipeline function is that your function can return rows one-by-one as opposed to building the entire result set in memory as a whole before returning it.

The above gives the obvious optimization - memory savings from something that would otherwise return big result set.

A fairly interesting example of [using pipelined functions is here](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/pipelines.html)

What seems to be a good use of them is ETL (extract/transform/load) - [for example see here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/38)